# I want to display a message in confirm dialog in javascript without using html or any other

Tags: javascript

I want to display a message "Do you want to delete?" in confirm dialog.

I had given that message in the data content, but it is not working.

How can i do this only by using javascript ?

Here is my code :

```
function confirmDelete ( a )
{   
$(function() {

    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      data : "Do you want to delete?",
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "YES": function() {
            $(this).load("./removeAgent.action?id="+a,  function() {
                $("#agentResult").trigger("reloadGrid");
            });
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "   NO    ": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });
});
```

}

Comment: Is the problem that the dialog doesn't display, or that on clicking "YES" nothing (or the wrong thing) happens? Have you included jquery.js on your page? Why do you have a document ready handler inside your `confirmDelete()` function?

Comment: The dialog box is getting displayed with only YES and NO buttons. But there is no message in that dialog box. I want to display the message "Do you want to delete?" in that dialog box. Please help me to display that message by using only this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method in onClick listener,

```
    <script>
        function clickAction()
{
        var result;
        var buttonpressed=confirm("Button Press");
        if (buttonpressed==true)
{
          result="OK";
          }
        else
{
          result="Cancel";
          }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=result;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using confirm method in javascript itself.

The html part

Click the button to display a confirm box.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

The JavaScript Part

```
<script>
    function myFunction(){
    var x;
    var r=confirm("Press a button!");
    if (r==true){
      x="You pressed OK!";
      }
    else{
      x="You pressed Cancel!";
      }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
    }
</script>
```

**Or**

If you want to use jquery plugins Lokk at the links below.

http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/confirm-box

http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/0.4.0rc1/